# Improve performance using geolocation to sort by distance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bigdata

I have to build the structure of a `posts` table to handle a big number of data (let's say, 1 million of rows) with with notably those two fields:

- `latitude`
- `longitude`

What I'd like to do is *optimise the time consumed by read queries, when sorting by distance*.

I have chosen this type: **decimal** (precision: 10, scale: 6), thinking it is more precise than **float**, and relevant.

Would it be appropriate to add an index on `latitude` and an index on `longitude`?

I'm always scared watching all the operation, such as `SIN()`, that ORM are performing to build such queries. I'd like to follow the best practices, to be sure it will scale, event with a lot of rows.

Note: If a general solution is not possible, let's say the database is MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Data structures, e.g. indexes, are often provider specific. Please clarify what exactly is your need (in regard to the databases types)

Comment: I just selected MySQL to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these composite indexes to the table:

```
INDEX(latitude, longitude),
INDEX(longitude, latitude)
```

Assuming you have `WHERE` clauses on both columns, the Optimizer will pick the better of those two indexes.  For further discussion and more advanced (faster) techniques, see [*Find Nearest*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

In there, I point out that 6 decimal places is probably overkill in resolution, unless you are trying to distinguish two persons standing next to each other.

There is also reference code that includes the trigonometry to handle great circle distances.